# Best way to switchover between 2 power supplies?

Tags: batteries, switches, dc, wiring

So I was trying to think of a way to make a circuit reversible across a DC-DC charger

See diagram below, it will normally be on case 1, but in some circumstances, it will be need be on case 2
[image]

The best way I can think of doing this is with 2 three-way change over switches, but would there be a better solution? What hardware should be used?

Comment: what do the diagrams mean?

Comment: The DC-DC charger will take power from battery 1, convert it into a suitable charging voltage and charge battery 2. But I am looking at a switch and wiring solution that could do the reverse.

Comment: are you saying that you want to use one battery to charge the other battery, and be able to select which battery is being charged and which battery does the charging?

Comment: what problem are you solving by adopting such a configuration?

Comment: It will be used on a RV, normally the alternator thus the car's battery will charge up the leisure battery, but in case of the car battery runs flat, I would like a way to switch over and to charge it up

Comment: The ground can be probably be connected permanently - it doesn't need switching. It could potentially be done with one two-pole changeover.

Comment: perhaps it may be possible to charge both batteries at the same time .... or use a jumper cable to start the engine from the leisure battery

Comment: I would not be surprised if a product already exists that can do this. Anyway, another option that accomplishes much the same thing is a simple battery selector switch. You can select battery 1, or battery 2 to be connected to the starter. Just don't switch while the engine is running.

Comment: https://www.marinco.com/en/2110a.  The idea here is that instead of trying to use the charger to recharge the starter battery, you just connect battery 2 to the starter (instead of battery 1) temporarily until you get the engine started.

Answer (score 0):

The above method must limit the charge current to each battery and also limit the voltage for OverV and UnderV protection using a buck type inductive switch for continuous operation until equalization and full charge or cutoff conditions are achieved. This might give some optimal (TBD defined)  CC , CV and cutoff states.

Current and voltage sensing is required for each controller port, as well as some indication of battery state.

Comment: The DC-DC charger would achieve that